# Copying backup table into similar table with new columns

Tags: sql

Copying data from a backup table into a production table is as easy as...

```
INSERT INTO TBL_A 
SELECT * FROM TBL_A_BK
```

However, if I add a new column to TBL_A after making my backup, I now have to specify every column in the INSERT statement and the SELECT statement.  The more columns in my table, the more frustrating this is, seems like there should be an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no easier way.  The correct method is to write:

```
 INSERT INTO TBL_A (col1, col2, ... colX)
   SELECT colA, colB, ... colZ FROM TBL_B
```

Any other method is fragile -- it's not at all obvious what should happen when one table has more columns than the other, or the columns are in a different order.

That said, you can easily write code in some application language that builds an ordered column list for each table from metadata and creates the SQL on the fly for you.

In addition, some languages (I"m thinking of an obscure one called R:Base, there are likely others) have other statements (in R:Base it's APPEND) that INSERT by matching column names, leaving others NULL.